# Execute commandline commands in c#

Tags: c#

I need to run cmd commands in a c# program im writing, the only solutions ive found make a new command line instance for every command, but i need them to be executed in the same instance

[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

```cs
public static void UpdateDeviceData()
        {
            Process.Start("CMD.exe",
                String.Format("client_commandline.exe setdeviceposition 0 {0} {1} {2}", LPos.X, LPos.Y, LPos.Z));
        }
```

Comment: `but i need them to be executed in the same instance`; may I ask why?

Comment: Note that it is not *needed* to use CMD.EXE to start other executable. You can start the other executable(s) directly, with their proper parameters. Doing so will be a bit more efficient, also it will not create a visible cmd.exe window (could it be that this is what you are aiming to solve with this?).

Comment: i found a solution, its this:
```csharp
Process CmdPro;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
   startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
   startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";

   CmdPro = new Process();
   CmdPro.StartInfo = startInfo;
   CmdPro.Start();
   Console.SetOut(CmdPro.StandardInput);
```

Comment: @Stefan i thought it needed to be in the same instance but apparently it doesnt need to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, its this:

```cs
Process CmdPro;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo; 
startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; 
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false; 
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe"; 
CmdPro = new Process(); 
CmdPro.StartInfo = startInfo; CmdPro.Start(); 
Console.SetOut(CmdPro.StandardInput);
```